# Time complexity of multiple for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, time-complexity

I was calculating the time complexity for a method that I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < P; i++){
  for(int j = P-1; j >= 0; j--){
          for(int k = 0; k < D; k++){}
          for(int z = 0; z < D; z++){}
  }}
```

D is always lesser or equal to P, but my doubt is in the two last fours. I have my time complexity as O(2P^3) but I've read the 2 can be removed like O(P^3). Is any of these correct?

Comment: Do you mean `j++` in the second loop?

Comment: Oops no, thats a mistake, its j--. I have corrected it!

Comment: You could declare i, j, k and z outside of your loops, this might increase speed.

Comment: @paladin that would have no impact whatsoever.

Comment: I'm pretty sure reducing time for memory allocation and garbage collection will also increase runspeed.

Comment: @paladin try writing with the declarations inside and outside the loops, and decompiling. The bytecode is identical, so there can't be any performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

`O(2P^3)` is equivalent to `O(P^3)`.

O-notation, specifically, describes how worst-case time/space usage increases based on the size of the input (in this case, it increases cubically, as opposed to linearly or quadratically). As such, we're interested in the *class* of that complexity - as `P` gets arbitrarily large, `2P^3` is increasingly indistinguishable from `P^3`, so we can ignore the coefficient `2`.

Meanwhile, if we were to compare the scaling to something that was `O(P^2)`, the resource usage would be much less as `P` got arbitrarily large. Even if we compared a complexity of `P^3` to a complexity of `(1000P^2)`, there's a point at which `P` gets so large that the factor of 1000 becomes insignificant, so we can ignore it.

Comment: Thank you! I was also wondering if I should calculate the time complexity as O(DP^2) or if O(P^3) was more correct since D can be equal to P

Comment: @Marizard If `D` is independent from `P`, then `O(DP^2)` would be correct. If `D` is derived from `P`, then `O(P^3)` would probably be more correct, but `O(DP^2)` wouldn't be incorrect, necessarily